# HTTP requests are not redirected to HTTPS by Apache for certain domains only

Tags: apache, http, redirect, https, smtp

I have a VPS running Apache as webserver and serving requests for a certain domain and related subdomains.
For each of these domain/subdomains, I have configured the redirection from HTTP to HTTPS, in this way:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName sub.domain.com
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sub.domain.com
                RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
        </VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName sub.domain.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub.domain.com
[...]
```

This configuration seems to work properly for all the domains, except for the one dedicated to SMTP (`stmp.domain.com`) for which the response seems to failback to the default configuration (and so, to the `index.html` file located in `/var/www/html/`); then, only the explicit HTTPS request seems to work fine, in that case.

How is this possible? Maybe are there some configuration files which overwrite that configuration? If yes, what should I check, in theory? For the `apache2ctl configtest` command, everything is okay.

**Oct 23rd Update**

As suggested in the comments, I activated the log for the rewrite module, by adding this line to `apache2.conf` file:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
```

I then tried to make a couple of HTTP requests to two different endpoints of the server and I compared what was going on via the logs. It seems that the rewrite rule is not reached for `smtp.domain.com` since I found only this print into the `access.log` file:

```
[23/Oct/2022:11:46:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 440 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
```

For the other configurations I confirm the rewrite rule works properly because I can see several prints in the log. For instance, for `imap.domain.com` I found this inside `error.log`:

```
[Sun Oct 23 11:39:09.846013 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2390:tid 140516244342528] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client MY_IP_ADDR] MY_IP_ADDR - - [imap.domain.com/sid#7fcc7e661df0][rid#7fcc7c4ec0a0/initial] applying pattern '^' to uri '/'
[Sun Oct 23 11:39:09.846144 2022] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 2390:tid 140516244342528] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client MY_IP_ADDR] MY_IP_ADDR - - [imap.domain.com/sid#7fcc7e661df0][rid#7fcc7c4ec0a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='imap.domain.com' pattern='=imap.domain.com' => matched
[Sun Oct 23 11:39:09.846166 2022] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2390:tid 140516244342528] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client MY_IP_ADDR] MY_IP_ADDR - - [imap.domain.com/sid#7fcc7e661df0][rid#7fcc7c4ec0a0/initial] rewrite '/' -> 'https://imap.domain.com/'
[Sun Oct 23 11:39:09.846182 2022] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2390:tid 140516244342528] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client MY_IP_ADDR] MY_IP_ADDR - - [imap.domain.com/sid#7fcc7e661df0][rid#7fcc7c4ec0a0/initial] explicitly forcing redirect with https://imap.domain.com/
[Sun Oct 23 11:39:09.846200 2022] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2390:tid 140516244342528] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client MY_IP_ADDR] MY_IP_ADDR - - [imap.domain.com/sid#7fcc7e661df0][rid#7fcc7c4ec0a0/initial] redirect to https://imap.domain.com/ [REDIRECT/301]
```

The main concern is that actually the configuration of `smtp.domain.com` differs from the one of `imap.domain.com` only by server name. Here is the result of `git diff`:

```
diff --git a/smtp.domain.com.conf b/imap.domain.com.conf
index f7778ee..cba26cb 100644
--- a/smtp.domain.com.conf
+++ b/imap.domain.com.conf
@@ -1,27 +1,20 @@
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
-               ServerName smtp.domain.com
+               ServerName imap.domain.com
 
                RewriteEngine on
-               RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =smtp.domain.com
+               RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =imap.domain.com
                RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
 
        </VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 
-               ServerName smtp.domain.com
-               DocumentRoot /var/www/html/smtp.domain.com/
+               ServerName imap.domain.com
+               DocumentRoot /var/www/html/imap.domain.com/
 
                # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
                # error, crit, alert, emerg.
```

Furthermore, in the main configuration file I didn't find any mention to `smtp.domain.com` so I suppose there is not any rule which overwrites the one in the domain configuration.

**Oct 23rd Further Update**

It seems that for requests to `http://smtp.domain.com` Apache uses the default configuration file (`000-default.conf`) instead of the custom one (`smtp.domain.com.conf`) which I reported here. In fact, by adding the same rewrite rule in the first one, the redirection works properly. Any of you can maybe explain me what is going on and why? Why are HTTP requests not managed via the custom configuration, even if there is a related branch of rules?

Comment: Looks like something is different in your setup of that http host. Maybe some additional rewriting rule somewhere? Or some application logic using a URL instead of a relative path? We cannot say, we do not know your setup.

Comment: You could enable rewrite logging in your http server. See the documentation on how to do that exactly. Rewrite logging allows to understand in detail what exactly is going on inside your rewriting engine.